# I get a "Specified method is not supported" error when i try to use ExcelDataReader to upload file to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, exceldatareader

I've written a method, BulkCopy, to upload my Excel file to SQL Server database table. I am trying to unit test this and it fails each time with "System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported".

If someone could have a look it would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Emmett

```
    public static void BulkCopy(string inputFilePath, string tableName)
    {

        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        var stream = File.Open(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString))
            {

                bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                reader.Read();
                var cols = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(i => reader.GetValue(i)).ToArray();
                foreach (var col in cols)
                {
                    var column = cols.GetValue(0).ToString();

                    if (column.Trim() == "Column 1")
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column, "Column 1");
                    }

                    if (column.Trim() == "Column 2")
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column, "Column 2");
                    }

                    if (column.Trim() == "Column 3")
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column, "Column 3");
                    }

                //continued for column mappings...

                }

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Copy data to database done (DataReader).");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What line of code is giving you that error?

Comment: Hi, I get this on bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code ,the issue is showed in the following code ,you reader is incorrect.

```
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
```

**Pass the datatable into bulk** , try the below code

```
public static void BulkCopy(string inputFilePath, string tableName)
    {
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        var stream = System.IO.File.Open(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        IExcelDataReader reader;

        if (inputFilePath.EndsWith(".xls"))
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
        else if (inputFilePath.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        else
            throw new Exception("The file to be processed is not an Excel file");
        var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
            {
                UseHeaderRow = true
            }
        };
        var dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(conf);

        // Now you can get data from each sheet by its index or its "name"
        var dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                reader.Read();
                var cols = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(i => reader.GetValue(i)).ToArray();
                foreach (var col in cols)
                {
                    var column =col.ToString();

                    if (column.Trim() == "Column 1")
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column, "Column1");
                    }

                    if (column.Trim() == "Column 2")
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column, "Column2");
                    }

                    if (column.Trim() == "Column 3")
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column, "Column3");
                    }

                    //continued for column mappings...

                }
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Copy data to database done (DataReader).");           
    }
```

**Pass the dataReader into bulk**, change your `foreach` part as shown

```
               for (var i = 0; i<cols.Count();i++)
                {
                    if (cols[i].ToString().Trim() == "Column 1")
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(i, "Column1");
                    }

                    if (cols[i].ToString().Trim() == "Column 2")
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(i, "Column2");
                    }

                    if (cols[i].ToString().Trim() == "Column 3")
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(i, "Column3");
                    }

                    //continued for column mappings...

                }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I have tested it and it works perfectly. The only thing is that I was hoping to avoid the need for using a DataTable to save the overhead. I think it should work using ExcelDataReader, per the DataReaderBulkCopySample() method example here: 

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0x4ee593e397a9eeebaca2bd45be323f565e38af84ae2da9e7ce43db1cac965b00&fullName=Program.cs&project=gSerP1983/OpenXml.Excel.Data

Only I keep getting this "Specified method is not supported" error still. I'm wondering if it's because I'm using asp.net core, but I'm likely wrong.

Comment: For using ExcelDataReader , use `public SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping Add(int sourceColumnIndex, string destinationColumn);` this method , please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, this now works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolved the issue , could you mark my reply as answer? This will help other people who faces the same or similar issue to find the answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way it's setting the column mappings. If you delete them it will work. In the example [link](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0x4ee593e397a9eeebaca2bd45be323f565e38af84ae2da9e7ce43db1cac965b00&fullName=Program.cs&project=gSerP1983/OpenXml.Excel.Data) you posted they are using `GetName` to get the columns. I tried that and it doesn't work for some reason. I get a `GetOrdinal` error. That's the same error that is coming from your code: `` ExcelDataReader.ExcelDataReader`2.GetOrdinal(String name) ``.

Not sure how pretty it is, but it works.

```
public static void BulkCopy(string inputFilePath, string tableName)
    {

        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        var stream = File.Open(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString))
            {

                bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                reader.Read();
                var cols = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(i => reader.GetValue(i)).ToArray();
                foreach (var col in cols)
                {
                     if (cols[i].ToString() == "Column 1")
                     {
                          bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(i, "Column 1");
                     }

                     if (cols[i].ToString() == "Column 2")
                     {
                          bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(i, "Column 2");
                     }

                     if (cols[i].ToString() == "Column 3")
                     {
                          bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(i, "Column 3");
                     }

                    //continued for column mappings...

                }

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Copy data to database done (DataReader).");
        }
    }
```